# Part of the url is being troncated when calling $location.path() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The function below is being called with no problem. the $save method is being called and my object is being added to mongodb. However, the problem lies in the $location.path() method. For some reason, the $routeParams.quizId is not being taken in account in the URL.

I can see in Chrome that the url it tries to reach is:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/quizes/questions/54a09a248ff7bf9816f272b9 404 (Not Found)
```

The quizId is missing, the URL should look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/quizes/quizIdRightHere1234/questions/54a09a248ff7bf9816f272b9


$scope.create = function() {
      var question = new Questions({
        value: this.value,
        type: this.type,
        answer: this.answer
      });

      question.$save({quizId: $routeParams.quizId}, function(response) {
        var quizId = $routeParams.quizId;
        var url = '/quizes/' + quizId + '/questions/' + response._id;
        $location.path(url);
      }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

RouteParams should happen after the hash sign... otherwise it's just different folders.

Comment: What do you mean, can you please give me an example?

Comment: Params can either occur after a ? mark or after a # mark.  For example www.google.com/folder1/2, in this url it is leading it to folder called '2' within another folder called '1'.  But if you want to add parameters then you can type www.google.com/folder1/2#/name/yang?surname=li.  In this case the parameter name = 'Yang' and surname = 'li'.  These are not recongised by the browser and thus will not trigger a refresh to look for the folder.

Comment: I am not trying to use URL parameters, I am only trying to concat a value from $routeParams in the URL.